# Ajax suggestion list problem in IE

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, internet-explorer

My "ajax suggestion list" is getting hide behind "select menu", placed exactly below the text box calling ajax functionality.  However its works perfectly in other browser but doesn't work with IE 6.0. Please suggest any solution.
Also i already off the autocomplete feature for that text box but some time it works, sometime doesn't. Is there any permanent solution for this problem without disabling this feature through browser control panel.

Thanks

Comment: Look up IE6 in Wikipedia.  The important information include "released on August 27, 2001", "widely derided for its security issues", and "eighth worst tech product of all time".  Let it go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about IE6, just stop supporting it or tell visitors that are on IE 6 to upgrade to a newer version. IE6 users are used to "ugly websites" anyway.

Anyway, have you tried adding a z-index CSS rule to your "ajax suggestion list"? Something like this:

> z-index: 9999;

Answer (score 3):

IE6 has issues with placing things over native controls such as `<select>`. If you're using jQuery then you can try the [bgiframe](http://brandonaaron.net/code/bgiframe/docs/) plugin, if you're not using jQuery then you can study the bgiframe source (it is quite small) and apply its techniques to your problem.

It would be nice to be able to tell people not to use IE6 but there are still a fair number of large businesses that are using it for various good and bad reasons: it came stock with XP and that's what the "enterprise" has standardized on, there are a lot of internal applications that only work in IE6 and no one wants to pay to rebuild them, etc. Life is hard and we have to support crufty old garbage like IE6 sometimes, too bad, who ever is paying the bills gets to call the shots so sometimes you just have to deal with it.